# jq - select object if condition on different object is met

Tags: arrays, json, object, select, jq

Let's say I have more namespaces with the similar k8s resource (some might have different images used). I am trying to get .metadata.namespace using jq from the following json object (let's call it test.json):

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "app",
                "namespace": "test1"
            },
            "spec": {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "database": {
                            "from": "service",
                            "value": "redis"
                        },
                        "image": "test.com/lockmanager:1.1.1",
                        "name": "lockmanager01",
                        "replicas": 2,
                        "type": "lockmanager"
                    },
                    {
                        "database": {
                            "from": "service",
                            "value": "postgresql"
                        },
                        "image": "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1",
                        "name": "jobmanager01",
                        "replicas": 2,
                        "type": "jobmanager"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

if following condition is met:

.spec.components[].type == "jobmanager" and .spec.components[].image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1"

but can't find the correct statement.

I tried:

```
cat test.json | jq '.items[] | select((.spec.components[].name? | contains("jobmanager01")) and (.spec.components[].image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1")) | .metadata.namespace''
```

but it returns all namespaces and, moreover, those I am interested in (because I know they contain different image), are returned twice.

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that the selection criterion is:

```
.spec.components[].type == "jobmanager" and
.spec.components[].image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1"
```

but that does not make much sense, given the semantics of `.[]`.

I suspect you meant that you want to select items from `.spec.components` such that

```
.type == "jobmanager" and .image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1"
```

If that's the case, you could use `any`, so that your query would look like this:

```
.items[]
| select( any(.spec.components[];
              (.name? | contains("jobmanager01")) and
              .image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1") )
| .metadata.namespace
```

### all distinct

If you want all the distinct .namespace values satisfying the condition, you could go with:

```
[.items[]
 | .metadata.namespace as $it
 | .spec.components[]
 | select( (.name? | contains("jobmanager01")) and
          .image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1" )
 | $it]
| unique[]
```

### Efficient version of "all-distinct" solution

To avoid unnecessary checks, if .namespace is always a string, we could write:

```
reduce .items[] as $item ({};
   $item.metadata.namespace as $it
   | if .[$it] then .   # already seen
     elif any( $item.spec.components[];
               ((.name? | contains("jobmanager01")) and
               .image != "test.com/jobmanager:1.1.1") )
     then .[$it] = true
     else . end )
| keys_unsorted[]
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe the goals using a much simpler JSON example or set of examples. Please follow the [mcve] guidelines in doing so.

Comment: Sorry, it works perfectly fine in all cases! Excellent answer, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to vote up for your answer :(

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get the examples working properly. What had gone wrong?

Comment: Don't kill me @peak, please. The real image path was a bit different, but I suddenly used the one provided here to test it. I do apologize.